# How to find the keywords that Google searchers are using to find my site

Tags: google, google-analytics, keywords, search, not-provided

I have been using Google Analytics for some time and unfortunately it hides the searches that have led users to click into my site.

Is there any reliable source where I could check the daily searches where my site has been printed and, if possible, clicked by users?

Comment: Besides Google Analytics and Google Webmaster Tools, which are the best, I use SEMRush which is excellent. The rest of the online tools are terrible including the best of the best. They are often 6 months behind. As well, these lists are often misleading. For example, the Google Webmaster Tools > Content Keywords list lists terms that does not seem to drive traffic to my site. I suspect that is not the case for all sites especially standard blogs and static sites, just know that this can be a factor.

Comment: @closetnoc I had a great experience with ahrefs, have you tried it?

Comment: @nunorbatista It has been a while. I have heard good things about it. I will check it out again.

Comment: @nunorbatista It appears to be back links only but it does appear to be more up to date than most if not all. Good tip!! I forgot about that one.